# Rolling Ball on User Controlled Rotatating Rectangle Help AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a game in Flash using as3. Here is my problem. The first part of the game is to keep the ball on the plank for x amount of seconds. I have been able to make the ball roll on the plank but cannot figure out how to take into account the y value of the ball... Here is my code.

```
function ballRollLeft(event:Event):void{
    ball.x=ball.x+plank.rotation;
    //ball.y++;
    if(ball.x<332.7){
        var yVel:Number = plank.rotation;
        var yAcc:Number = plank.rotation;

        ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move3);
        function move3(event:Event):void{
            ball.y-=yVel;
            yVel+=yAcc;
            }
    }
}

function ballRollRight(event:Event):void{
    ball.x=ball.x+plank.rotation;
    //ball.y=ball.y-plank.rotation;
    if(ball.x>572.7){
        var yVel:Number = plank.rotation;
        var yAcc:Number = plank.rotation;

        ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move3);
        function move3(event:Event):void{
            ball.y+=yVel;
            yVel+=yAcc;
            }
        }
}
```

It works to make the ball roll left and right but the y value does not change and when the ball gets close to the edge it flies off and down.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: you may want to update the title to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trace ball.y, yVel and yAcc and make sure they're not NaN or 0.  Force a value in the initialization of yVel and yAcc.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, when I trace the values I get:319.2
undefined
undefined...This may be a dumb question but how do I force a value for them if they are coming up undefined? Thank you

Comment: what are the vars your tracing - what is 319.2?  Trace plank.rotation as well as the ball.x, ball.y